# Error en salida de datos C

Tags: java, c

Tengo un problema, estoy aprendiendo C y estoy "traduciendo/convirtiendo" mi codigo de Java a C para hacerlo mas eficiente, solo que tengo un problema en la salida:
Se supone que la salida debe ser 11 15 18 , pero solo sale el 15 correctamente y los demas no.
El programa hace la suma de datos en la misma posicion.
De antemano, gracias por la ayuda.
Codigo JAVA

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    n = leer.nextInt();
    int a[] = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            a[j] += leer.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Codigo C

```
int main(){
int n,aux=0;
scanf("%i",&n);
int a[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        scanf("%i",&aux);
        //printf("%i ",aux);
        a[j]+=aux;
        aux=0;
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%i  ",a[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Salida en C

```
 10165323  15  10163090
```

Usando:

Entrada

```
3
1 2 3
3 4 5
7 8 9
```

Salida esperada

```
11 15 18
```

Comment: @Trauma hay un bucle for interno que repite `n` veces la solicitud de valores para añadir.

Comment: @Crxwler Porqué no muestras una traza de los valores que va tomando `a[j]`?

Comment: Ya lo solucione, por alguna razon tenia que inicializar todas las posiciones del arreglo en 0, gracias de igual manera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int a[n];
```

Ahí estás reservando espacio para almacenar `n` elementos de tipo `int`... pero las posiciones de memoria no se inicializan manualmente, por lo que si no las inicializas a mano tendrán valores aleatorios (basura).

Te falta esto:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  a[i] = 0;
```

O esto:

```
memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
```

El hecho de que solo el segundo caso sea correcto es azar (depende de cómo dejen la memoria las instrucciones anteriores)

Answer (score 0):

Te has dado cuenta de que hay que inicializarlas a cero pero tiene su porque.

En c al declarar una variable se esta reservando un espacio de memoria, este espacio ha podido ser usado con anterioridad por otro programa y ha dejado datos  que denominaremos basura para tu programa actual.

Al reservar la memoria y no quitar la basura, lo que estas obteniendo son los datos que habia previamente.

Las variables globales por otro lado si inicializan a 0 si tu no les das un valor.